# Code "Skipping" response listener in JSON object request (Volley)

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley, spotify

I am currently working on an app and I would like to read all of the songs from a Spotify playlist given it's ID. I am using Volley, Gson, and the spotify android authentication. I have successfully managed to obtain a list of all the users playlists from the Web API,However after adding the song reading class, when I run the application the array of songs returned is empty, and in the debugging panel it seems that the program skips the responseListener( I also added multiple Log statements that didn't print to make sure). This is my first android app and I am a newcomer to Volley so I appreciate any help.

Here is the SongReader Code:

```
public class SongReaderSpotify {
    private static final String ENDPOINT = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists";
    private SharedPreferences msharedPreferences;
    private RequestQueue mqueue;
    private ArrayList<Song> slist = new ArrayList<Song>();
    private String playlistid;
    private String templink;
    public SongReaderSpotify(RequestQueue queue, SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String id) {
        mqueue = queue;
        msharedPreferences = sharedPreferences;
        playlistid = id;
         templink = ENDPOINT +"/" +playlistid +"/tracks";
    }

    public ArrayList<Song> getSongs() {
        return slist;
    }

    public ArrayList<Song> get(final VolleyCallBack callBack) {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, templink, null, response -> {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Log.d("RESPONSE",response.toString());
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.optJSONArray("items");
                    Log.d("RESPONSE",response.toString());
                    for (int n = 0; n < jsonArray.length(); n++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(n);
                            Log.d("RESPONSE OBJECT",object.toString());
                            JSONArray artistarr = object.optJSONArray("artists");
                            object = object.optJSONObject("track");
                            Song s = gson.fromJson(object.toString(), Song.class);
                            Log.d("SONG FIELDS",s.toString());
                            List<Artist> temp = new ArrayList<Artist>();
                            for(int i =0;i<artistarr.length();i++)
                            {
                                //GETTING Artists
                                try{
                                    JSONObject o = artistarr.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Artist a = gson.fromJson(o.toString(),Artist.class);
                                    Log.d("ARTISTNAME",a.getName());
                                    temp.add(a);
                                }
                                catch (JSONException e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            s.setsArtists(temp);
                            slist.add(s);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    callBack.onSuccess();
                }, error -> {
                    // TODO: Handle error

                }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                String token = msharedPreferences.getString("token", "");
                String auth = "Bearer " + token;
                headers.put("Authorization", auth);
                return headers;
            }
        };
        mqueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        Log.d("SONGLIST", slist.toString());
        return slist;
    }

}
```

(None of the log statements inside the response code printed, only the SONGLIST one did.)

This is the calling of the code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        authenticateSpotify();

        msharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("SPOTIFY", 0);
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    }
    private void authenticateSpotify(){
        AuthorizationRequest.Builder builder = new AuthorizationRequest.Builder(CLIENT_ID, AuthorizationResponse.Type.TOKEN, REDIRECT_URI);
        builder.setScopes(new String[]{SCOPES});
        AuthorizationRequest request = builder.build();
        AuthorizationClient.openLoginActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE, request);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        // Check if result comes from the correct activity
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            AuthorizationResponse response = AuthorizationClient.getResponse(resultCode, intent);

            switch (response.getType()) {
                // Response was successful and contains auth token
                case TOKEN:
                    editor = getSharedPreferences("SPOTIFY", 0).edit();
                    editor.putString("token", response.getAccessToken());
                    Log.d("STARTING", "GOT AUTH TOKEN");
                    editor.apply();
                    waitForInfo();
                    break;

                // Auth flow returned an error
                case ERROR:
                    // Handle error response
                    break;

                // Most likely auth flow was cancelled
                default:
                    // Handle other cases
            }
        }
    }
    private void waitForInfo() {
        UserPlaylistsSpotify playlistService = new UserPlaylistsSpotify(queue, msharedPreferences);
        playlistService.get(() -> {
            Manager.GetInstance().userPlaylists = playlistService.getPlaylists();
            for(Playlist p : Manager.GetInstance().userPlaylists){
                SongReaderSpotify songservice = new SongReaderSpotify(queue,msharedPreferences,p.getId());
                songservice.get(() -> {
                    p.pSongs =  songservice.getSongs();

                });
            }
            startMainActivity();
        });



    }

    private void startMainActivity() {
        Intent newintent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, testact.class);
        startActivity(newintent);
    }
```

For reference here is the script that retrieves a users playlists:

```
public class UserPlaylistsSpotify {
    private static final String ENDPOINT = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists";
    private SharedPreferences msharedPreferences;
    private RequestQueue mqueue;
    private ArrayList<Playlist> plist = new ArrayList<Playlist>();

    public UserPlaylistsSpotify(RequestQueue queue, SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
        mqueue = queue;
        msharedPreferences = sharedPreferences;
    }

    public ArrayList<Playlist> getPlaylists() {
        return plist;
    }

    public ArrayList<Playlist> get(final VolleyCallBack callBack) {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, ENDPOINT, null, response -> {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.optJSONArray("items");

                    for (int n = 0; n < jsonArray.length(); n++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject imgobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(n);

                            JSONObject plobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(n);
                            Playlist p = gson.fromJson(plobject.toString(),Playlist.class);
                            JSONArray loopar = imgobject.optJSONArray("images");
                            List<Image> temp = new ArrayList<Image>();
                            for(int j = 0; j < loopar.length();j++)
                            {
                                //GETTING IMAGES
                                try{
                                    JSONObject o = loopar.getJSONObject(j);
                                    Image i = gson.fromJson(o.toString(),Image.class);
                                    temp.add(i);
                                }
                                catch (JSONException e)

                             {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            p.addToImages(temp);
                            plist.add(p);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    callBack.onSuccess();
                }, error -> {
                    // TODO: Handle error

                }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                String token = msharedPreferences.getString("token", "");
                String auth = "Bearer " + token;
                headers.put("Authorization", auth);
                return headers;
            }
        };
        mqueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        return plist;
    }


}
```

The user retrieval seems to work so I can't understand why the song reading wouldn't, I consulted the Spotify API and aside from the path parameters(which I supplied) the only parameter needed is the authorization token.

Here is the logcat if it helps (The last error is because I tried to call toString on a null array):

```
2020-01-24 14:57:03.717 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/STARTING: GOT AUTH TOKEN
2020-01-24 14:57:03.742 17922-17955/com.example.switcheroo D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe7c85540: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe7c836f0)
2020-01-24 14:57:03.742 17922-18007/com.example.switcheroo W/cr_CrashFileManager: /data/user/0/com.example.switcheroo/cache/WebView/Crash Reports does not exist or is not a directory
2020-01-24 14:57:04.293 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo W/mple.switchero: Accessing hidden field Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->theUnsafe:Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (light greylist, reflection)
2020-01-24 14:57:04.340 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/ENDPOINT: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/5tSCpEXtiHvlhSQneDTgXL/tracks
2020-01-24 14:57:04.341 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/SONGLIST: []
2020-01-24 14:57:04.341 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/ENDPOINT: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/3RKyX5h0a24jHAK3PSMRcG/tracks
2020-01-24 14:57:04.342 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/SONGLIST: []
2020-01-24 14:57:04.342 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/ENDPOINT: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/78awFOWllGbEH0Nskl7Rnh/tracks
2020-01-24 14:57:04.342 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/SONGLIST: []
2020-01-24 14:57:04.342 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/ENDPOINT: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/37i9dQZF1DX6I0cdp2bBlZ/tracks
2020-01-24 14:57:04.342 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/SONGLIST: []
2020-01-24 14:57:04.342 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/ENDPOINT: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/37i9dQZF1DX186v583rmzp/tracks
2020-01-24 14:57:04.343 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/SONGLIST: []
2020-01-24 14:57:04.343 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/ENDPOINT: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/5AQkVd2L8aRfGheTDKYpLi/tracks
2020-01-24 14:57:04.343 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/SONGLIST: []
2020-01-24 14:57:04.343 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/ENDPOINT: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/3Zu0udhojTUyjnFfnfYrMP/tracks
2020-01-24 14:57:04.343 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/SONGLIST: []
2020-01-24 14:57:04.343 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/ENDPOINT: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/3NSc2VAy6kGPcaPzmONQlx/tracks
2020-01-24 14:57:04.344 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/SONGLIST: []
2020-01-24 14:57:04.344 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/ENDPOINT: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/0Z89HetVHGGCYLCKx1EG7i/tracks
2020-01-24 14:57:04.344 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/SONGLIST: []
2020-01-24 14:57:04.344 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/ENDPOINT: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/3ZkFvyGwLLSBHZc3aamjEl/tracks
2020-01-24 14:57:04.344 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/SONGLIST: []
2020-01-24 14:57:04.344 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/ENDPOINT: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/37i9dQZF1DZ06evO2QRN3G/tracks
2020-01-24 14:57:04.345 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/SONGLIST: []
2020-01-24 14:57:04.345 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/ENDPOINT: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/37i9dQZF1DZ06evO30Opqw/tracks
2020-01-24 14:57:04.345 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/SONGLIST: []
2020-01-24 14:57:04.345 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/ENDPOINT: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/37i9dQZF1DZ06evO1BFaJa/tracks
2020-01-24 14:57:04.345 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/SONGLIST: []
2020-01-24 14:57:04.345 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/ENDPOINT: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/37i9dQZF1DZ06evO1CSf4Y/tracks
2020-01-24 14:57:04.346 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/SONGLIST: []
2020-01-24 14:57:04.348 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/ENDPOINT: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/3EMdqZxxfOIrlhQyiHaNfk/tracks
2020-01-24 14:57:04.348 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/SONGLIST: []
2020-01-24 14:57:04.376 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@7956216
2020-01-24 14:57:04.600 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-01-24 14:57:04.602 17922-17922/com.example.switcheroo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.switcheroo, PID: 17922
```

I'm also a new to shared preferences however after some debugging it seems that the songreader got the same token the playlist reader had.

I've been stuck on this problem for a while so any help at all is appreciated! Thanks in advance :)